Preventing data leakage in time-series data splitting
I am working on a fault detection problem for a mechanical system where the goal is to determine the fault type. I use a dataset that for each type of fault (target label) has three sizes and each fault size has four different working conditions as shown in the following figure. Note that each sample in the dataset is a time-series and because the number of samples is too small and also they are too long, it's necessary to split each sample into fixed-length chunks. Now the question is how to assign each chunk to the training or test set in a way that ensures a fair and unbiased evaluation.

In prior studies, the common practice is to randomly split all chunks into training and test sets.

Using this approach, neural network models often achieve near-perfect performance on the test set. However, this approach appears fundamentally flawed because dividing approximately stationary signals into chunks results in highly similar chunks from the same signal and similar chunks may end up in both sets, causing significant data leakage. To illustrate this data leakage, I applied the t-SNE algorithm to the chunks.

In this figure, each color corresponds to a particular fault type and fault size. Notice that chunks from the same sample are clustered closely together. Here is a zoomed-in version of figure:

I think the chunks should be split based on the fault size. For example, the chunks of the samples with fault size 1 and 2 should be included in the training set, while the chunks of samples with fault size 3 should be in the test set. This ensures that no information from the training signals is present in the test set.

Now I want to ask:

Is my claim about data leakage correct? If so, are there additional methods to demonstrate data leakage more rigorously, such as using similarity metrics or other visualizations?
What do you think of proposed split approach? Does splitting based on fault size adequately prevent data leakage? If not, what alternative splitting strategies would you recommend to ensure a fair evaluation?

Edit: In response to the comments, I will try to clarify some points. In my application, the size of faults in different setups can vary greatly, so it's important that the model can detect faults without being exposed to signals related to different fault sizes. Ideally, we would include signals for different fault sizes in the training set, but this is impractical. On the other hand, it is expected that a model trained on two fault sizes will struggle to perform well on a third, unseen fault size. This begs the question: "How much similarity between the train-test split is acceptable?" If the answer is that it depends on the application, then in my case, signals related to some fault sizes should remain unknown during testing since this reflects the conditions in production.
As already mentioned by @Ggjj11, in my proposed approach, the split is repeated, and the average accuracy is reported. Specifically, in the first iteration, signals related to small and medium fault sizes are included in the training set, while signals related to large fault sizes are included in the test set. In the second iteration, small and large fault sizes are included in the training set, while medium fault sizes are included in the test set. The third iteration follows a similar pattern. After some research, I found that this approach is known as GroupKFold cross-validation.

First of all, just because the train and test splits are similar doesn't mean there is leakage. Now I'm not sure i completely understood your description, but if there is some situation like you record a "failure event" that lasts for, say 60 seconds, you split this event into two 30-second chunks, put the first chunk in the train set and the second in the test set, then yes that would be a form of data leakage.

@SimonSegert I agree, similar splits doesn't mean there is leakage. I think the root cause of the problem is that it's unknown how much similarity is reasonable. Yes, the way you have described is the way that splitting is done.

+1 for repeated cross-validation (I.e. the scheme which you propose) if you are not retraining the model with each new time series. I also think that having data from the very same series both in the test and training set makes the performance estimation too optimistic, see pseudoreplication.

Is it correct, that in your proposal, observations with large faults are only in the test set? If so, how would your model learn to detect faults of such observations, when it has only ever seen small and medium faults in the training?

Without knowing your use case very well it is hard to make a specific recommendation on the groups you should split on. Ideally (without specific use cases in mind), you have the same distribution of data in your test and train set. So you would prefer to have all kind of independent faults in the test and train set. This rule of thumb can only be disregarded if you have proper logic which is use-case specific. One example could be anomaly detection where you just do not have enough anormal observations and they would not matter in the training, so then you might just put them to the test set

@Ggjj11 I've updated the question—please take a look. Could you clarify what you mean by "if you are not retraining the model with each new time series"? Are you suggesting that GroupKFold cross-validation should be used in this problem?

@picky_porpoise I've updated the question to address the point you raised. Please have a look and let me know your thoughts.

In my comment above "if you are not retraining" means: imagine you train a model on these random splits, but your use case makes sure that prior to real inference you make sure to train the model auch that parts of the current data generating process realization is fed into the training set (in a reasonable sense), then this "retrained" model could perform similarly like you evaluated on your old test set ... This goes by the name of transductive ML https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transduction_(machine_learning) or semi-supervised ML... The evaluation strategy should reflect the deployment

@Ggjj11 If I understand you correctly, you’re saying that in supervised learning, where the model is not retrained for new samples, repeated cross-validation with the splits I’ve proposed is the correct approach. However, if the model is retrained for each new sample, a different evaluation strategy would be more appropriate. Is that what you mean? Apologies if I’ve misunderstood your point.

Yes this is my point (sorry for the typos above). From my experience proper retraining on new samples (in a transductive  setting) is barely seen in the real world... People typically shy away from such a complex pipeline, which is barely generalizing if you need to retrain on every new sample) ... People typically look for generalizing models ...

@Ggjj11 Thank you, no problem. Yes, that’s typically what we expect from a model. Additionally, in some cases, retraining with new samples can be quite time-consuming.

Roberts, David R., Volker Bahn, Simone Ciuti, Mark S. Boyce, Jane Elith, Gurutzeta Guillera-Arroita, Severin Hauenstein, et al. “Cross-Validation Strategies for Data with Temporal, Spatial, Hierarchical, or Phylogenetic Structure.” Ecography 40, no. 8 (August 2017): 913–29. https://doi.org/10.1111/ecog.02881.

Let me quote:
"Pseudoreplication occurs when observations are not statistically independent, but treated as if they are. This can occur when there are multiple observations on the same subjects, when samples are nested or hierarchically organised, or when measurements are correlated in time or space." from https://bmcneurosci.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2202-11-5
So obviously, when your time-series has autocorrelation and only decays slowly but you split it into a test part and a train part some information is leaked from the train to the test set.
Another popular problem is a "batch effect" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_effect
If you split a time-series with a batch effect this specific realization of the batch effect (like e.g. a systematic mean shift) is leaked to the test set (while you are blank for new realizations of a batch effect with a different mean shift)
Beyond the two above problems (pseudo replication and batch effects) there is probably even more problems with too optimistic, biased performance estimation on the test set if you do not properly group-split in your test-train set cross-validation (if it is repeated cross-validation or any other form of cross-validation).
So if you want an unbiased performance estimation I would recommend going with the splitting scheme which you proposed.
If there is good arguments for the other evaluation strategy (like a) the decay of the autocorrelation function, b) no batch effects, c) no interest of transfer to another time-series, you are solely in a forecasting setting of e.g. one single stock ),then you might go with the other time based splitting scheme - it depends on your use case.
Update: please read this awesome reference from Ben Bolker's comment: https://nsojournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ecog.02881
It discusses the points raised by me in a great way

Thanks for the answer. My understanding of the paragraph "There is probably even more problems with too..." is that incorrect data splitting during each iteration of cross-validation amplifies the issue because the process is repeated. Is my interpretation correct?

Well, typically you perform repeated cross-validation to improve your performance estimation (and reduce the uncertainty of it). Now, when groupings are not correctly accounted for, this approach of repeated CV will not help in itself, because the root cause (the groups) are not treated appropriately. Therefore, it is important to treat those groups correctly, otherwise you run into pseudo replication, batch effects and probably a lot more phenomena due to this (would be interesting to see if others have more phenomena in their mind).
